# Running time of for loop with i=i*2

Tags: algorithm

what will be the running time of the following code?

```
    for(i=1; i<= n; i=i∗2)
```

the outer loop run log_2(n) times so, what is the running the of inner loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**PS:** Last summation is equal to `2(n - 1)` which is `O(n)`.

Comment: can you please elaborate the function

Comment: @MaG Last part is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: Finally, an answer that actually proves something. +1

Comment: @MaG For the first line it iterates log(n) times which the `i` index in the summation(differs from `i` in the code) shows this. Second loop iterates until `2*i`. Third line is just `O(1)` operation (i.e the `1` in the summation).

Comment: @MaG  Three lines of code mapped into an equation with two summation and one constant(I hope it was clear in my answer/comment). The equation is straight forward to solve. I don't understand how you reach `logn + 2i`.

Answer (score 2):

As inner loop is increasing linearly it won't have any impact on itself from outer loop. So it will run **n times.** And in this case **n** will change in accordance with the value of **i**.

Comment: Not really MaG, inner loop will get value from outer loop, suppose outer loop has a value of i = 4 then inner loop will run from 1-4 times. Which is linear.

Comment: @MaG It is `O(n)`. To prove that for each loop you can write a summation...

Comment: @Prashant Its `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Well the easiest is to try an example (which is not proof, but it depends, if you have to prove it, or just finding correct answer is enough)

So for n=1024

```
i=1
i=2
i=4
i=8
i=16
....
up to 1024
```

Extra info: The outerloop is run log_2(n) times (but we dont need this information for calculating)

The inner loop is run with the value of i, which is

```
1+2+4+8...+1024=1024*2 - 1 = 2*n - 1 = O(n)
```

The answer: There will be up to `2*n - 1` Hello printed. It can be lower if the n is not in this format `2^k=n` where k is whole number. It can be lower by half (n=512 and n=1023 will have same results)

```
(Hellos printed) >= n AND (HELLOS printed) <= 2*n - 1
```